# Webpack node process.cwd() and path.resolve() return '/'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Pretty much the title, not sure what I have misconfigured...
Other solutions I looked at suggested adding `target: node` but I am using webpack to bundle react, so my target shouldn't be nodejs, right ?

Webpack configuration :

```js
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;
console.log(mode);

module.exports = {
  entry: ['react-hot-loader/patch', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/public'),
    publicPath: '/public/js/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  mode,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: [{ loader: 'eslint-loader' }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: { presets: ['@babel/preset-react'] },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: { 'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom' },
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: './public',
    compress: true,
  },
  node: { __dirname: true, __filename: true },
```

```js
console.log(__filename);     // returns src/components/Play/components/Lobby.jsx
console.log(__dirname);      // returns src/components/Play/components
console.log(process.cwd());  // returns /
console.log(path.resolve()); // returns /
```

Adding more text to be able to post this. More Details have been added to post this. I am sorry I am not sure what I could describe more about this issue that I am having...

Answer (score 1):

Since you've configured `node: { __dirname: true, __filename: true }`, webpack will replace `__dirname` and `__filename` while bundling ([see docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)). This is why you're seeing the value you expect from `console.log(__dirname)` when your code runs. Keep in mind that the directory `src/components/Play/components/` doesn't actually exist after bundling – all of your code is in that single `bundle.js` file.

As for `process.cwd()`, what do you expect to get for the current working directory when your code is running in a web browser? The code running in your browser has no access to the filesystem where your code was written, and so returning `/` as the cwd seems reasonable enough.